# Can a dead fish be made to twitch via electrostimulation?

Tags: electrophysiology, history, electromuscular

Galvani in the 1700s famously showed that a dead frog can be made to twitch by electric stimulation. The hind legs are particularly susceptible. Salt helps in the activation, as shown in these videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJifWqUa2pY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YZJt_Bw3eo
Can the same be accomplished with a fresh dead fish? Fish are more easily available for demonstrations to children. Have you tried this, and if so which part of the fish is most readily stimulated?

Comment: This is quite immediately post-mortem; we aren't talking grocery store frogs, if that's what you're thinking.

Answer (score 2):

With fish, the hearts can be stimulated to beat just by prodding them.

Learnt a long time ago, preparing fresh fish given to me by others.

Comment: Works with mammals, including humans, too.